Socket.io not receiving request
I have three HTML files, JS attached, and also the Server
Home, this just allows the client to either create a room or join through a UUID.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Kahoot Clone</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Kahoot Clone</h1>
    <button id="createRoom">Create Room</button>
    <input type="text" id="roomId" placeholder="Room ID">
    <button id="joinRoom">Join Room</button>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>

const socket = io();

document.getElementById('createRoom').addEventListener('click', () => {
    socket.emit('createRoom');
    window.location.href = 'teacher.html';
});

document.getElementById('joinRoom').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const roomId = document.getElementById('roomId').value;
    socket.emit('joinRoom', roomId);
    window.location.href = 'student.html';
});

Student
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Student's Room</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Starting Soon...</h1>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>const socket = io();</script> 
</body>
</html>

Teacher screen, which should log if a student has joined the session through the UUID generated in the console, this is the file I cannot seem to get any information in
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Teacher's Room</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Teacher's Room</h1>
    <p>Your Room ID: <span id="roomIdDisplay"></span></p> 
    <div id="joinedStudents"></div>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="teacher.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>

const socket = io();
const joinedStudents = document.getElementById('joinedStudents');
const roomIdDisplay = document.getElementById('roomIdDisplay');


socket.on('roomId', (roomId) => {
    console.log('Received roomId:', roomId); 
    roomIdDisplay.textContent = roomId; 
});


socket.on('studentJoined', (message) => {
    joinedStudents.textContent = message;
});

And my Server javascript file that is using Express and Sockets.io as the back-end
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid'); // For generating room IDs


const path = require('path'); 

// Serve static HTML files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); 

// Handle Socket.IO connections
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    // ... (Inside the io.on('connection'... block)
    socket.on('createRoom', () => {
        console.log('Teacher created a room')
        const roomId = uuidv4(); // Generate a unique ID
        console.log(roomId);
        socket.join(roomId);
        socket.emit('roomId', roomId); // Send ID back to the teacher client
    });
    socket.on('joinRoom', (roomId) => {
        console.log('Student joined room:', roomId);
        socket.join(roomId);
        io.to('teacherRoom').emit('studentJoined', 'A student has joined');
    });
});

http.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
});

For some reason, the teacher script is not firing back to me the roomId, and if a student has joined, I don't understand why it's not connecting when I've looked at the documentation and done it appropriately.

when you change location the web socket connection terminates

I see, but how am I supposed to create rooms then?

you could pass those id's between the pages (also, wait for receiving them before redirecting).. but I think simplest would be just to use 1 page and toggle '' visibility instead of redirect.

OK, that's what I'll do thank you very much, I looked more into it and you're right, a spa would be better for my use case.
